# preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 127

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, console

No specific answers or direction when googling this error - why does it happen,what does it mean and why? When I select `Show Errors`, there is nothing. It is a solution with a console project as startup, which references a library. VS-Code, Ubuntu 20.04.  Relevant files? below:

`launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/RTM_Console/bin/Debug/net6.0/RTM_Console.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/RTM_Console",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "justMyCode": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

`Program.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoFac" Version="6.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="autofacserilogintegration" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.enrichers.context" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.enrichers.environment" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.enrichers.process" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.enrichers.thread" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.extensions.hosting" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.settings.configuration" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.sinks.console" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="serilog.sinks.file" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RTM_Lib\RTM_Lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>CopyAlways</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [

            "${workspaceFolder}/RTM.sln"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
            },
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: See following : https://www.errorvault.com/en/troubleshooting/runtime-errors/microsoft/windows/error-127_windows-error-127?force_isolation=true

Comment: I added that this is on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You may need to update the kernel.  See : https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/?force_isolation=true.  Most likely there is a compatibility issue between the app, windows and the kernel.